# Redireccionar a una vista JSP por medio de un botón

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

Tengo una aplicación en `java Spring MVC`.
Este es una parte de mi código `JSP`.

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${datos}" var="dato">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${dato.codigo_Pers}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${dato.nombre_Pers}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${dato.apellido_Pat_Pers}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${dato.apellido_Mat_Pers}" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Modificar" id="btnModificar" >
                <input type="button" value="Eliminar" onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controladorPersona/eliminarPersona?codigoPers=${dato.codigo_Pers}'">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Este fue mi último intento con `JQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnModificar").click(function(){
        window.location.href="ModificarPersona.htm";
    });
});
```

Aquí muestro la imagen del árbol de mi proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y en esta imagen muestro el resultado de mi proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como ven solo me funciona en la primera fila de la tabla, más no en las demás. Un favor pueden ayudarme en el código `JQuery` para arreglar esto. Se les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás usando un **id** para asignar el listener `$("#btnModificar")` como los id's deberían ser únicos, te lo asigna solo al primer botón. Lo puedes solucionar agregando un **class** a los botones:

```
<input type="button" value="Modificar" class="btnModificar" >
```

y en el js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btnModificar").click(function(){
        window.location.href="ModificarPersona.htm";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que `Spring` trabaja por medio de `clases Controller`, lo que debes hacer es llamar a un método del `controller` y que este `controller` redirija a la pagina que necesitas.

por ende el **modificarPersona.html** debe ser una clase no una pagina, ya que no se pueden llamar directo

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "modificar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Modificar(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        return "pagina";
    }
```

De la misma manera que llamas a la pagina bienvenido.